# manipulating asp.net controls with java script

Tags: javascript

I have  4 radio buttons in my form. I have change checked status of these controls through JavaScript. This is not a radio button list. 4 separate radio buttons. How can I get the checked buttons and how do I change these checked status through JavaScript.
 Because, this will reduce server processes. This is necessary in my form..

Comment: Please show us your code / markup. We are no wizards

Answer (score 0):

To check: `document.getElementById("oneRadio").checked = true`

To uncheck set it to `false`

Then you can check using this:

`if(document.getElementById("oneRadio").checked == true){...}`

Answer (score 0):

To change the stauts of your radio button to checked or unchecked you can try this:

```
document.getElementById('YourRadioButtonID').checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ASP.NET validation controls as they are designed to do their validation checks using JavaScript in most browsers. This gives you the benefit of using client side code when possible:

> If the user is working with a browser that supports dynamic HTML
>   (DHTML), ASP.NET validation controls can perform validation using
>   client script. Because the controls can provide immediate feedback
>   without a round trip to the server, the user experience with the page
>   is enhanced. Under most circumstances, you do not have to make any
>   changes to your page or to the validation controls to use client-side
>   validation. The controls automatically detect if the browser supports
>   DHTML and perform their checking accordingly. Client-side validation
>   uses the same error display mechanism as server-side validation.

See [Client-Side Validation for ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb52a4x0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information